# Logging processing waiting in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Hello I'm trying to write a logging script for 2 processes which should run in simultaneously but the logging fails and only the logging files are created but no data from stdout gets streamed to them. Heres my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mate-terminal -x rcssserver
mate-terminal -x rcssmonitor


mate-terminal -x ./main team 127.0.0.1 > logs/player

mate-terminal -x ./main -t 127.0.0.1 > logs/trainer
```

Additionally I would like to wait for both commands logging and the stop rcssserver and rcssmonitor when they have returned to parent process. Is any of this possible?

Comment: Do you know the difference between stdout and stderr?
Try something like `mate-terminal -x ./main team 127.0.0.1 2>&1>> logs/player`. I use `>>` so it will append not overwrite.

Comment: Yeah I know the difference I would like to see both outputs, but I tried your idea and It does not redirect anything to those files I tried catting them but they are empty.

Comment: Does `mate-terminal -h > logs/player` show something. Is logs an existing directory? Did you try adding `echo Help > logs/myhelp` ? Does mate-terminal show something in the console when you don't redirect? Do you see something with a wrong ip-dres (127.0.0.33 or 127.I.am.wrong).